# Where can I find the full enumeration for the font.highlightColor property in WordApi 1.1?

Tags: office-js

I have looked everywhere for this and cannot find the actual list of colors that are allowed for highlighting. I looked in the project files created via the yeoman-generator and Visual Studio 2017, intellisense for office-js, the Word JavaScript API Reference dev.office.com, on Github, etc.

I ask because there is at least one more color that can be used for highlighting than is available in the MS Word desktop application's color palette that can be used (i.e., white), and because I would like to use the color names instead of the hex values.

Comment: It is my understanding that the colors available for the 'highlightColor' property (e.g., 'searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor') are a subset.  For example, orange/#FFA500 is not available in the desktop app through the pallet or VBA.  Similarly, I cannot get this code to do anything: searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor = 'orange'  or this searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor = '#FFA500'

Comment: then maybe the OpenXML HighlightColorValues https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.highlightcolorvalues

Comment: Ah, I think you are right. Black was another color I was able to get to work, and all of the other colors on the OpenXML list are in the color palette on the desktop app.  Thanks.